# jQuery. animate. array. variables. selectors. next / previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an animation for lego instruction.

I declared variables, which are options and count, so I need to select it to animate in order.(but I dont know how to call the variables as selectors.) when I click the two buttons, 'next, and 'back.'

I also need to set the 'reset' button to go to the first page.

Any helps will be very appreciated. Thank you.

[This is the rough image of how it looks.](http://jayleejunha.com/Tom_parking_lot_asmt1/lego_web/jquery_selector.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = ['legs', 'body1', 'cape1', 'cape2', 'head1', 'helmet1']
    var count = 0;

    $('.back').click(function() {

        if (count > 0) { count--; } ** $('') ** .eq(count).animate({ top: '250px' });
    })

    $('.next').click(function() {

        $('').eq(count).animate({ top: '250px' }, 'slow');
        count++;
    })

    $('.reset').click(function() {
        count = 0;
        $('').html('');

    })

});
```

Comment: Can you post the html code too, will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to Reset animation in your case

```
// Reset animation
reset.click(function(){
    for (i = cnt; i >= 1; i--) {
      e = $('.components').find('img')[i];
      $("#" + e.id).stop().animate({ top: top }, {
        complete: function() { $(this).removeAttr('style') }
      });
      $("#" + e.id).removeAttr("style");
    }
    init();
});
```

Jquery

```
var e;
var top;
var cnt = 0;
var next = $('.next'); 
var back = $('.back');
var reset = $('.reset');
function init(){
  cnt = 0;
  back.addClass( "disable" );
  next.removeClass( "disable" );
  reset.addClass( "disable" );
}
var eleCnt = $('.components').find('img').length;
init();
$(document).ready(function(){
  reset.click(function(){
    for (i = cnt; i >= 1; i--) {
      e = $('.components').find('img')[i];
      $("#" + e.id).stop().animate({ top: top }, {
        complete: function() { $(this).removeAttr('style') }
      });
      $("#" + e.id).removeAttr("style");
    }
    init();
  });
  next.click(function(){
    back.removeClass( "disable" );
    reset.removeClass( "disable" );
    if(eleCnt > cnt){
      cnt += 1; 
      if(cnt==eleCnt-1){
        next.addClass( "disable" );
      }
      e = $('.components').find('img')[cnt];
      if(e){
        top=$("#" + e.id).css('top');
        $("#" + e.id).animate({top: '248px'});
      } else {
        cnt -= 1; 
      }
    }
  });

  back.click(function(){
    if(cnt > 0){
      if(cnt == 1){
        back.addClass( "disable" );
        reset.addClass( "disable" );
      } else {
        next.removeClass( "disable" );
        back.removeClass( "disable" );
      }
      e = $('.components').find('img')[cnt];
    }
    if(e){
      $("#" + e.id).stop().animate({ top: top }, {
        complete: function() { $(this).removeAttr('style') }
      });
      $("#" + e.id).removeAttr("style"); 
      if(cnt > 0){cnt -= 1;}
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the working code:https://jsfiddle.net/5zhb60m3/4/

I think it should be helps you,.